# Regex pattern to look for a word

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following Regex pattern to remove all characters after the 2 line breaks.

```
(?<=.+[\r\n]+.+[\r\n]+)([\s\S]*)
```

My problem here is that I also wanted to add a check for a specific text, for example after that 2 line breaks and if it is found, do not include it.

And here is how I do it on my c# code:

```
string newComment = string.IsNullOrEmpty(regexPattern) ? emailBody : new Regex(regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Replace(emailBody, string.Empty);
```

**EDIT**

I wanted to look for a specific text, for example "This is a signature:" then if it is found, it should not be included and anything after it also, while maintaining the current design which everything after 2 line breaks will not be included

Sample strings:

```
string body = "Try comment.";
string additionalBody = "This is a signature";
string newBody = body + System.Environment.NewLine + additionalBody + System.Environment.NewLine + "asd Asd";
```

So the `newBody` should result to 3 paragraphs text.

It should display the "Try comment" only.

Possible scenarios may be:

1) On the first or second paragraph, the text can be present and should be removed automatically.

2) If the automated signature is not present but there is 3 paragraphs, remove the last paragraph.

Comment: "*My problem here is that I also wanted to add a check for a specific text, for example after that 2 line breaks and if it is found, do not include it.*" — It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

How about simply:

```
(?<=(?:.+[\r\n]+){2})([\s\S]*)This is a signature
```

Comment: @M42:  \R not exist in .NET

Comment: @walidtoumi: Too bad :-(.

Comment: @Gerald: Please show some sample input strings and expected result.

Comment: @Gerald: Is the added sentence `This is a signature:` or `This is an automated signature`?

Comment: @Gerald: just remove the `:` from regex, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?<=(?>.+[\r\n]+){2})(?:(?!\bThis is a signature\b)[\s\S])*
```